# I am trying to reconstruct a 3D model of a anatomical structure (Knee) using X- ray images.I am using C++ coding in opencv

Tags: c++, opencv

I want to extract lines of a X-ray image. I have used canny and sobel operators. But there are some unnecessary features. How can I extract only the boundaries of the bone by removing others??

[image: Canny operator used image]

Comment: show original image

Comment: Have you tried morphological operations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really a programming question, so you can probably get better answers by posting to the signal processing stack exchange: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/

I would try varying the parameters of your Canny and Sobel operators. If that doesn't give better results, you could try more advanced operators, as described here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canny_edge_detector#Improvement_on_Canny_edge_detection and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sobel_operator#Alternative_operators

You could also try processing your image in multiple stages. For the image in your question, I would do a second analysis to remove any white dots/lines that don't have a lot of neighbors. You would probably lose some information too, but it would remove most of the noise.